# Oracle Rman configuration parameter

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

i was backing up the control file though RMAN.
i put the database in  mount mode and take the backup of controlfile .
i configure the controlfile autobackup on.by default it was off. after taking the backup. when i open the sqlprompt and put database in nomount mode, and delete controlfile thinking i ll recover it ,AGAIN GOING TO RMAN PROMPT . when i fire command SHOW ALL;
CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF; # DEFAULT

MY QUES IS WHY CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP IS GOING OFF WHEN I TURNED IT ON.
And how to make changes permananent.

Comment: maybe is Dba question

Answer (score 0):

As you said: "... take the backup of controlfile ... configure the controlfile autobackup on ... after taking the backup... delete controlfile thinking i ll recover it" 
At the time you backup controlfile - the current setting of "CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP" is still "OFF", you change it into on, drop it, then restore, leading to the status is still "OFF".
If you want to keep it ON - just set it before taking backup.